# Voting on "closer"?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, closed-questions, users

For example, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/best-practices-that-you-disagree-with) was closed:

> closed as not constructive by Walter♦ 10 hours ago

It would be cool if there was an option of down voting the closer/close.

---

Also, why was one person able to close this? Shouldn't it require five votes?

Comment: This is getting silly now. You have already asked [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75296/how-to-not-get-mad-when-people-close-good-questions) question and as you didn't get the agreement you wanted, you have started another question. The sites need to be moderated and someone (be it one person or a collective group) needs to have the final say.

Comment: Has Evan got a cousin?

Comment: If you wanted a suspension you could just have fired the team an email....

Comment: @Barry ok, i don't talk to you guys anymore. have a good life and those two questions have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 12):

That one person is a moderator (the diamond after their name indicates this) - whose votes are binding.

If 5 3K+ users disagree they can vote to reopen the question thus overturning the decision. So if you have 3K+ reputation on the site you can add your vote to reopen.

If you don't have 3K+ reputation you can either:

1. Add a comment and hope that 5 3K+ users see it and agree with you.
2. Flag the question and explain why you think the question should be reopened. The other moderators will see this and if they agree with you can reopen the question (again with a single vote).

Finally you can raise a question on the site's own meta where you can bring it to the wider community.

Answer (score 3):

One person can close questions only if he is the Moderator. The person Walter you have given in your question is a moderator and hence he has the rights to close the question.

The question linked by you also has reasons on why it is closed. You can read that link which says six guidelines for constructive subjective questions. If you still feel this question should be re-opened, you can add a comment as **ChrisF** has suggested in his answer.